# Java: Clase cuyo atributo esta en dos idiomas distintos

Tags: java, uml

Estoy trabajando con Java7, Spring, JPA e Hibernate y tengo una duda dobre un caso de uso de los requisitos que me han dado.

Contexto: la aplicación trata sobre un servicio de hermandades de Semana Santa. En ella, existen diferentes actores; Member, que será la persona que se unirá a la hermandad, y Brotherhood, que será aquella que acepte al Member y le asignará una posición.

Member y Brotherhood están relacionadas a traves de una clase asociación llamada Enrollment. Dicha clase es la que tiene el atributo Position(que es una clase a parte, o al menos así lo he considerado yo), que será nulo hasta que el Member sea aceptado por la Brotherhood.

Hasta ahí todo bien. El tema está en que las positions pueden estar en español y en inglés, y me gustaría añadir funcionalidad de escalado para poder agregar nuevos idiomas en el futuro. La cosa es que no se como modelarlo. Como hacer que Enrollment y Position estén relacionados y que según el idioma elegido para mostrar la página salga en un idioma o en otro.

Adjunto imagen del modelado actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El idioma es una restriccion de uso, no del sistema.. no debe estar en el diagrama UML.. o no deberia...

Comment: O sea.. alguien va a tener una position ID de tipo 1.. que sera algo en ingles y algo en español y algo en frances y algo en japones.. pero el ID, es el mismo...

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder y por la aclaración de arriba.
¿Pero entonces debe tener un nuevo atributo tipo String por cada idioma que use la position?
Había pensado en una lista de String donde se fuesen añadiendo la position en los distintos idiomas pero no sabría cual coger para mostrar la página en un idioma determinado

Comment: Y que tal si lo que almacenas en la bd es el código del nombre del atributo y por otra parte tienes un diccionario que traduzca eso a nivel de vista, o necesitas obligatoriamente que los nombres estén en la bd?

Comment: Lo que dice @zerocool es una de las soluciones posibles. Tu sistema es independiente de los lenguajes que ocupe. La traduccion la hacen las vistas. Dentro de tu sistema, no importa el idioma que se use.

Comment: Hmmm. @zerocool no necesito obligatoriamente que los nombres estén en la bd. La posibilidad que he visto y que va por donde tú dices es usar el id o el código del nombre para en las vistas usar Spring:message code y dependiendo del código y del idioma del sistema actual salga un mensaje u otro. Hasta ahí todo correcto. Uso messages.properties para sacar de ahi los códigos para la etiqueta de Spring.

Comment: Pero la cosa está en que si quiero añadir nuevas posiciones tendria que añadir nuevas entradas a messages y a messages_es y si quiero más idiomas(ya que ahora solo tengo español e inglés ) debería crear nuevos archivos messages por ejemplo messages_fr y añadir códigos en dichos archivos y eso no se ahora mismo como podría hacerlo
Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda

Comment: Eso es un problema de vista. Nada que ver con tu sistema @Raikonen. No impacta para nada en lo que tiene que hacer tu sistema.

Comment: Vale @gbianchi, pero también tengo que implementar las vistas. Pongamos que solo tengo que usar inglés y español, que es lo que viene en los requisitos. Pero si añado nuevas posiciones, ¿Cómo podría traducirlas a través de las vistas?

Comment: Si eso sería correcto pero es igual si lo dejas en la bd, al ingresar una nueva posición tendrías que agregar el idioma para todos los que soportes. Si eso lo delegas a un usuario imaginate decirle que debe tener que buscar un traductor solo para crear una posición, incluso para un administrador sería tedioso. Por otra parte, es más escalable y menos riesgoso tener los archivos que tener eso en la bd, piensa que los archivos los puedes versionar mucho más facil, puedes incluso pedir la colaboración para traducirlos en un proyecto en github, etc..

Comment: Que el sistema permita que sea traducido es un requisito funcional que nada tiene que ver con el diagrama UML de tu sistema.

Comment: Vale, entramos ahora en código Java. Tengo una serie de positions predeterminadas y con ellas vendran una serie de códigos y mensajes en los archivos messages(Esta es la forma en la que he trabajado y como me lo piden, usando recursos de i18nl10n). Pero al añadir nuevas positions el administrador se supone que se deben agregar nuevos códigos y mensajes a dichos archivos para que Spring: message los use

Comment: puedes hacer un files tipo es, en, fr, con un json object dependiendo del idioma configurado llamas al archivo `x` y la structura de ambos es igual asi que dependiendo del idioma es `print(json["error"]["login"]["user"]) or  print(json["error"]["login"]["password"])` o manejado por id que es lo mas facil que seria  `print(json["error"][274])` or ``print(json["success"][22])` esta es la forma microsoft,oracle , sap etc... asi pueden buscar en su web el tipo de error y porque se da, tambien  asi si deseas puedes incluir soporte de varios idiomas asi lo requieras

Answer (score 0):

¡Aquí vamos! ¿Cual es la diferencia entre un `Chief Supervisor` y un `Jefe de Supervisión`?

Sintácticamente mucha, en letras tambén, pero la relación de equivalencia que existe es semántica, es decir significan lo mismo.

La forma correcta de manejar este tipo de valores para que tu modelo sea consistente es mediante el uso de valores enumerados.

```
_______________________
|   <<enumeration>>   |
|    Position         |
|_____________________|
| CEO                 |
| TD                  |
| PM                  |
| TL                  |
|_____________________|
```

es decir, cada posición tiene un valor real o un valor clave.

luego solamente debes pensar en una función para convertir de enumeración a cadena.

```
__________________________________________________
|   <<enumeration>>                              |
|    Position                                    |
|________________________________________________|
| CEO                                            |
| TD                                             |
| PM                                             |
| TL                                             |
|________________________________________________|
| +getJobName(language:LanguagesSupported):String|
|________________________________________________|
```

Y como podrás haber intuido, `LanguagesSupported` es también una enumeración, de esa manera tienes una solución fácil de modificar para agregar o quitar tanto posiciones como lenguajes soportados.

Si observas en mi propuesta, el método `getJobName` puede ser modificado en su implementación para obtener la descripción del puesto desde una BDD o un archivo, un servicio web o cualquier otra cosa según se necesite, pero el código arquitectónico no requeriría prácticamente modificaciones en ese caso.

Algo que pocas veces nos enseñan y siempre deberíamos de tener en cuenta es que en los negocios el cambio es la regla, no la excepción, nuestros modelos de solución deberían de de estar a la altura.